# How does Outlook deal with temporary data encrypted with S/MIME?

Tags: security, microsoft-outlook, encryption, temporary-files, smime

We are using S/MIME to encrypt messages and their attachments and Outlook as email application. All documents sent in attachment are stored on an encrypted folder and should never be copied anywhere else.

I want to know if Outlook creats a temporary file where it copies the documents before to encrypt them. If yes, how can I be sure the temporaly data have been securely deleted and cannot be retrieved by someone who has physical access to the computer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Outlook creates temporary file in **OutlookSecureTempFolder** each time you're opening the attachment. You can learn more on this folder in Microsoft [KB 817878](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817878). The only good way to completely secure the process of opening attachments is to specify your custom **encrypted** directory for OutlookSecureTempFolder registry value. You'll also be able to control its content as you wish.